# How to convert float percent value to integer percent?

Tags: php

How to convert float percent number value to integer  percent number value in PHP?

Example: 3.8461538461538 % = 4 %

Update: 
Here is my code ,  I coded to get percent value, but I get decimal value, but I need it without decimal value.

```
$total = array_sum($total_count);
$percent = ($occurs/$total)*100;
echo $percent ; 
echo "%";
```

Comment: What did you try? (And what is the *type* of the value? A string? A number?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php number_format(3.8461538461538); ?>
```

You can specify in second argument the number of decimal points (default is 0).

Comment: @Jennifer number_format() is for converting number formats. To be specific, to create comma separated currency values and henceforth. And hence, it is going to be heavier than round() in many ways.

I don't get why it's the 'correct' answer  instead of round() .  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is done with [round()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) - Rounds to closest int

```
<?php 
echo round('3.8461538461538'); //4
?>
```

There is also:

[floor()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) -- Round fractions down.

[ceil()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) -- Round fractions up.

Answer (score 2):

use `round()` . it's a PHP function.

**Edit:**
Given Code:

```
$total = array_sum($total_count);
 $percent = ($occurs/$total)*100;
 echo round($percent). "%";
```

For eg:

```
$number="3.8461538461538%";   //if it's a string with % in the end.
$number=substr($number, 0,-1);  //It type converts automatically here. Lazy code :)
$number_rounded=round($number);
```

or

```
$number=3.8461538461538;  //If it's just a float.
$number_rounded=round($number);
```